# SQL Group by Week Date

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am trying to group a list of orders in SQL Server by week date.  Using the SQL below i get the following results:

```
SELECT cast(datepart(wk, created) [week], count(1) [number of orders]
FROM Orders
GROUP BY datepart(wk, created)

Week - Number of Orders
15   - 305
16   - 285
17   - 428
```

What i want to do is instead of showing the Week number i want to show the week start date e.g.

```
Week -       Number of Orders
11/04/2016   - 305
18/04/2016   - 285
25/04/2016   - 428
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does your week start on Sunday or Monday?

Comment: Week starts on Sunday, though it would be good to see an answer with Monday too.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives me Mondays..

```
SELECT  DATEADD(Week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, created), 0) [week], 
        count(1) [number of orders]
FROM    Orders
GROUP BY DATEADD(Week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, created), 0)
```

If above gives you Monday, this should give you Sunday

```
DATEADD(Week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, created), -1)
```

Comment: I think this is close, but not quite right. For me it seems to return a week that starts with a Monday, but it counts items that happened during the 7 day period that begins the day _before_ that Monday. Hmm.

Comment: @samthebrand from what i remember, this depends on what your `DateFirst` value is set to.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, created), CAST(created AS DATE)),
        COUNT(*)
FROM    Orders
GROUP BY
        DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, created), CAST(created AS DATE))
```

You can control the week start day by using `SET DATEFIRST`.

Comment: WEEKDAY is a DAX function so won't work for me.  Is there something similar in TSQL.